# Selecting area upstream in watershed tool of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, watershed

How do I calculate the watershed at several locations using the watershed tool of ArcMap?

When I am doing it, I get the watershed cut at all the points, and not all the watershed upstream. I set the processing extent and the snap raster to the flow direction raster in the watershed tool, but this does not solve the problem. Also, the points are correctly located in the stream (snap pour points).

As you can see in the image below, the watershed for that particular station gets cut when finding the next station and does not consider the area upstream.

[image]

Comment: You have said nothing about the base DEM that you are deriving your catchments from, may be it as a flaw in it that causes the watershed tool to fail? Was the DEM built for hydrological analysis? See the topo to raster tool for more information.

Comment: I have derived the flow direction raster using hydrology tools and the DEM is from SRTM data

Comment: Did you run fill sinks before you attempted to use the DEM for catchment generation?

Comment: This is how watershed works, do them one by one using model or script if you don't know how they relate.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I solved it using model builder and calculate the watershed one by one

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68617713/820534